# Find difference of one row value with remaining row values in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Initial Dataframe:

```
df = 
             Index   Nature  Interval
0            0       1       0.000000
1            1       1       0.999627
2            2       1       1.000607
3            3       1       1.000612
```

The total number of entries are somewhere around 700,000.

Is there any way to find the difference between one element in the "Interval" column with all remaining elements in the same column and the same has to be done for the remaining dataframe.

I have found a workaround for this problem. The snippet is

```
df["Potential"] = df["Interval"].apply(lambda x:print(np.sum([math.exp(-4 * abs(x - val)) for val in df['Interval']])))
```

However it takes too much time, simply because of the for loop used.

So is there any way to optimize the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
b = df["Interval"].apply(lambda x: np.sum(np.exp(-4 * (x - df.Interval).abs())))
print (b)
0    1.054885
1    3.010498
2    3.014339
3    3.014319
Name: Interval, dtype: float64
```

Numpy solution substract reshaped values of `Intrval` column to 'row' and then apply `abs`, `np.exp` and `np.sum`:

```
val = df.Interval.values
arr = np.sum(np.exp(-4*abs(val-val.reshape(len(df.index),-1))), axis=0)
print (arr)
[ 1.05488507  3.01049841  3.0143389   3.01431861]

df["Potential"] = arr
print (df)
   Index  Nature  Interval  Potential
0      0       1  0.000000   1.054885
1      1       1  0.999627   3.010498
2      2       1  1.000607   3.014339
3      3       1  1.000612   3.014319
```

Another numpy solution, thanks `piRSquared`:

```
i = df.Interval.values
print (np.exp((np.abs(i[:, None] - i)) * -4).sum(1))
[ 1.05488507  3.01049841  3.0143389   3.01431861]
```